# JavaFX onInputMethodTextChanged not called after focus is lost

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I got something like this in mi fxml file:

```
<TextField fx:id="id" onInputMethodTextChanged="#foo" prefWidth="200.0" promptText="" />
```

But when I run it, I TAB or mouse out of the TextField control and nothing happens ("foo" isn't called) .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `onInputMethodTextChanged` property of `TextField` is applicable only if the `ConditionalFeature.INPUT_METHOD` is supported by the platform. To check this try

```
Platform.isSupported(ConditionalFeature.INPUT_METHOD)
```

If you are trying to do some work when the user focuses out from textfield, try

```
textField.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
        if(!newValue) {
            System.out.println("Focusing out from textfield");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, even with Platform.isSupported(ConditionalFeature.INPUT_METHOD) == true

The event handler which I set with setOnInputMethodTextChanged was not firing.

I was concerned about using TextField.textProperty.addListener(ChangeListener listener) because ChangeListener.change() does not, by itself, give you easy access to the source node which triggered the event.

I worked around by using:

```
final TextField field = new TextField("field");
field.textProperty.addListener(new ChangeListener() {

 public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {

   dosomethingwith(field);

}

});
```

Declaring field as "final" allowed me to get access to the source Node of the change event within ChangeListener.changed()